# hiddenview inside datalist

Tags: c#, asp.net

i have a datalist and inside it i bind a value in a label like this

```
  <asp:Label ID="hf1" runat="server" Visible="false"><%# Eval("DeptId")%></asp:Label>
```

how can i get the value of label in datalist EditCommand?

Answer (score 2):

Use `HiddenField` instead of Label with `Visible="false"`. You may obtain the reference of control in DataList via `FindControl(id)` method.

Markup:

```
 <asp:HiddenField ID="HiddenField1" runat="server" Value='<%# Eval("DeptId") %>' />
```

Code in EditCommand:

```
HiddenField h=e.Item.FindControl("HiddenField1") as HiddenField;
```

Answer (score 0):

`Visible="False"` will not render any content to the page.  Use a `<asp:hidden>` control instead:

```
 <asp:hidden ID="hf1" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("DeptId")%>' />
```

Answer (score 0):

With the Label you can also get the controls in EditCommand event as below:

```
protected void dlData_EditCommand(object source, DataListCommandEventArgs e)
{
    Label hf1 = (Label)e.Item.FindControl("hf1");//Any control you can find here
}
```

Also if you need to filter data item only in that case just put a condition:

```
protected void dlData_EditCommand(object source, DataListCommandEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.Item)
    {
        Label hf1 = (Label)e.Item.FindControl("hf1");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use style(css) to hide that element.So that it can be rendered in code behind file where you want to find the value of Hidden field.
Just use

```
  <asp:Label ID="hf1" runat="server"  style="display:none"><%# Eval("DeptId")%></asp:Label>
```

instead of

```
  <asp:Label ID="hf1" runat="server" Visible="false"><%# Eval("DeptId")%></asp:Label>
```

then everything will work fine for you.
Thanks 
Gourav